# Tomcat Log Analyzer

Tags: log-analysis

I would like to analyze tomcat logs for potential issues. I found [one here web-log-analyzer](https://code.google.com/p/web-log-analyzer/). I would like to know if similar tools exists.

Wanted features.

- Open source or freeware
- Find response times (min/max/avg), most used URL
- easy installation
- active community
- help files

Not necessary but nice to have

- scriptable
- Ability to issue SQL queries like Microsoft Log Parser (this on)
- Cross platform

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)**, in which you can centralize all logs you have, you can then perform crossed search. It's a freeware, a bit heavy but awesome.

You can also use **[Lambda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/d/index.htm)**, but it's more for global managment, not especifically for logs.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, Winged Panther! But could you please [edit] your post and point out how each recommended product meets the requirements stated by the OP (e.g. "easy installation", "active community", scriptable, cross-platform)? For a raw guide, you might wish to refer to [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185). This would make your answer more helpful, also to others. Thanks in advance!